# Why is my Azure App Service charging two plans?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have several App services, some of them are on a Free tier and some of them are on a Shared tier. 
For some reason Azure is charging both plans for each App Service and I don't undestand why.
[image]

Also, I checked their App Service Plan and it is on a Free Tier.

Any insights on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pricing question, not a programming question.

Comment: Pricing questions are off-topic here. That said, I'm not sure I understand the issue you're having, as you've only shared a snapshot of part of your bill. And we have no details here about any deployments etc. Perhaps open a billing support ticket with Azure? (billing support is free).

Answer (score 1):

Try to list all your App Service Plans (the compute behind an App Service) in the Azure Portal. ("All services" and the App Service Plans in the navigation) This will give you an overview of App Service Plans and how many "apps" you have on them. Technically you can have an App Service Plan with no apps but with cost.

When you create new App Service (Web, Api ect.) you can choose to create a new App Service Plan or re-use an existing. You can therefore end up with re-creating new App Services Plans (with billing also) everytime you create and App Service.

Also be aware that when you scale out (more instances) you are billed for every instance (as a seperate App Service Plan).

[List of App Service plans in the Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2rx9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your App Service has a connected service (like Application Insights) that exists on another plan? Or if you have a deployment slot on the App Service that belongs to another plan?